# How to get the user profile from access token Auth0

Tags: asp.net-web-api, .net-core, auth0, jwt

First of all, I am new to Auth0 and I don't have a good knowledge when it comes to security.

I have an application that uses React as the client and Dotnet Core as the back end API. I have successfully integrated the Auth0 with both client and server sides. From the client, I can successfully log in using Auth0 and get the access token, and call to a protected route in backend API.

From the API I want to get the user profile corresponding to the access token.

I followed [this](https://auth0.com/docs/quickstart/webapp/aspnet-core-3/02-user-profile) tutorial but I am getting null for all as well as claims.

Apart from that, I have decoded the access token from [JWT.IO](https://jwt.io/) then I noticed that there are no values in the payload that I'm looking for.

From another tutorial, they said that I have to include scopes of the request from the client. But that didn't help either.

```
auth0 = new auth0.WebAuth({
domain: AUTH_CONFIG.domain,
clientID: AUTH_CONFIG.clientID,
redirectUri: AUTH_CONFIG.redirectUri,
audience: AUTH_CONFIG.audience,
responseType: 'token id_token',
scope: 'openid profile email name'
```

});

On the client, I am getting 2 tokens after a successful login.

1. Identity Token: Which includes all the information that I need. But can't use as a bearer token to call my endpoint
2. Access Token: Which I can use as a bearer token to call to the endpoint, But there is no useful information in the payload.

I don't know the way I am following is wrong or not. If there is any other way please help me.